# Updating service workers on single page webapps

Tags: single-page-application, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I work on a single page webapp and am implementing service workers. I've learned that I need to manually update the service worker because a single page app doesn't have traditional navigation events, however, I'm unclear about the roles of `clients.claim()` and `self.skipWaiting()`.

Do I need to call these functions after manually updating the service worker? I've seen `skipWaiting()` called in the `install` event, and `claim()` called in the `activate` event handler. If I need either or both of them, are these the correct places to make these calls?

Answer (score 0):

[`clients.claim()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#activate) usually called in the install event to take control of uncontrolled clients once service worker is activated.

> It only really matters on the very first load, and due to progressive
>   enhancement the page is usually working happily without service worker
>   anyway.

For [`skipWaiting()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase), this causes your service worker to kick out the current active worker and activate itself as soon as it enters the waiting phase (or immediately if it's already in the waiting phase). It doesn't cause your worker to skip installing, just waiting. It's pretty common to call it in the `install` event.

> This must be called when updating the service worker.

For more information, you can check the [service worker lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle) documentation.